# Css full opacity for accordion menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, dom-events

When I drag table on background it effects clicked menu. I want to make invisible the grey lines from background:

[image: Grey lines and inside new tab]

Menu Area code:

```
<div id="jquery-accordion-menu" class="jquery-accordion-menu white" style="overflow: hidden auto; height: calc(100vh - 445px); width: 100%;"><ul><li><a href="javascript:;">
```

on background Selected Area code:

```
<td class="w2ui-grid-data w2ui-selected w2ui-inactive" id="grid_queryData_data_0_0" col="0" style=""><div style="max-height: 64px;"><span class="w2ui-info w2ui-icon-info" style=""
```

[image: Grey Lined part]

[image: Menu]

I will be grateful if anyone could help me.

Comment: Can you provide a working code?

Comment: I can't actually the code is too long because it's a company project.I added new images.

Comment: only the relevant code, we don't need the entire css or html, without it it is very difficult to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue with adding **z-index** with lower value for given method and higher **z-index** for accordion menu's css.